# Spring Boot and RethinkDB save JSON of unknown structure

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, rethinkdb

I develop Spring REST API. One of its endpoints must receive JSONs of unknown structure. To be exact, all JSONs has common header, but the inner document differs:

```
{
  "receiveData": {
    "iBusData": {
      "requestUID": "11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555",
      "messageKind": "PublishedData",
      "sender": "ST-DELLIN-307",
      "senderDateTime": "2018-10-15T09:09:09",
      "typeName": "typeContractor",
      "currentSenderApplication": "GP",
      "objectUID": "09876543-rrrr-aaaa-nnnn-ddddddddddddd",
      "data": {
        "contractor": {
          "uid": "09876543-rrrr-aaaa-nnnn-ddddddddddddd",
          "name": "Test_Contractor",
          "marked": false,
          "code": "763764568763",
          "isGroup": false,
          "fullName": "Test_Contractor",
          "INN": "Test_Contractor",
          "personalIDKindName ": "Test_Contractor",
          "personalIDSeries": "7634",
          "personalIDNumber": "18-111111111",
          "contractorCategory": "Test_Contractor",
          "contractorOPF": "Test_Contractor",
          "federalCategory": "Test_Contractor",
          "regionalCategory": "Test_Contractor"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Payload of `data` field may be different. All this nested documents (`contractor` in the example above) need to be stored in JSON-oriented database `RethinkDB`.

How to implement endpoint that cat receive JSONs with different structured in the `data` field?

Now I thought up to parse all JSONs as HashMap:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> all(@RequestBody HashMap json)
```

split HashMap to header and document and to store in database. But there are some difficulties:

- I need to select stored documents in the same format that they comes to endpoint
- I need to compare nested documents using `SHA256` and update them in the database
- I need to add three custom fields to the document before storing in the database

How to do all this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a classes for the body that has the common fields [you call a header].

Request body class

```
class MyRequest {
  BusData iBusData;
}
```

Class to hold the dynamic data

```
class BusData {
  String requestUID;
  String messageKind;
  // other fields

  // unknown json structure
  HashMap<String, Object> data;
}
```

When you receive this type of request body, to insert in reThinkDB - I think you could iterate the keys/values in the hashmap, and determine if the value is another object, then recursively iterate, building a query.
You'll probably need to pass the querybuilder parts by reference to methods during the recursion.

I don't have experience with rethinkdb, so I can't provide an implementation here.